# How can i use $watch in changing column value in a table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-watch

In my project-I have two columns in a table.you can see that in below picture.
[image]

What i want that is-- in "Non Receive Quantity" column if i change some value it will effect accordingly to "order quantity" column.Ex.In first row --Non Receive Quantity is 4 ,if i decrease it to 3 then Order Quantity will be 6 from 7.If i increase Non Receive Quantity from 4 to 5 then Order Quantity will be 8 from 7.
**How can i do that using angularjs $watch?**
**My Code:**
In my html--

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Procuct Code</th>
                            <th>Product Name</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Unit Price</th>
                            <th>Order Quantity</th>
                            <th>Non Receive Quantity</th>
                            <th>Total</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="pr in prodDetails">
                            <td>{{pr.PRODUCTCODE}}</td>
                            <td>{{pr.PRODUCTNAME}}</td>
                            <td>{{pr.DESCRIPTION}}</td>

                            <td>
                                <div ng-class="{ 'has-error' : poForm.unitprice{{$index}}.$invalid && submitted }">
                                    <input ng-model="pr.RATE" type="text" name="unitprice{{$index}}" ng-blur="getTotal(pr)" class="form-control input-sm" required />
                                </div>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <div ng-class="{ 'has-error' : poForm.poquantity{{$index}}.$invalid && submitted }">
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="pr.POQUANTITY" name="poquantity{{$index}}" ng-blur="getTotal(pr)" class="form-control input-sm" required readonly/>
                                </div>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <div ng-class="{ 'has-error' : poForm.quantity{{$index}}.$invalid && submitted }">
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="pr.QUANTITY" name="quantity{{$index}}" ng-blur="getTotal(pr)" class="form-control input-sm" ng-change="OrderQuantityChange(pr)" required />
                                </div>
                            </td>

                            <td>{{pr.TOTAL}}</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>Total Quantity: {{po.TOTORDERQTY}}</td>
                            <td>Total Price: {{po.TOTALPRICE}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

In Controller data entering in prodDetails--

```
function prepareProdDetail(detailLst)
        {
            scope.prodDetails = [];
            //scope.prodDetailsCompare = [];
            scope.products.forEach(function (prod)
            {
                var selProd = Enumerable.From(detailLst).FirstOrDefault(null, function (x) {
                    return x.PRODUCTCODE == prod.PRODUCTCODE;
                });
                if (selProd != null) {
                    prod.isSelect = true;

                    scope.prodDetails.push(selProd);
                    //scope.prodDetailsCompare.push(selProd);
                }
                else
                {
                    prod.isSelect = false;
                }
            });

        }
```

What i want to do/something like this--

```
function OrderQuantityChange(row)
        {
            scope.$watch('row.POQUANTITY', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                row.QUANTITY = row.QUANTITY+(oldValue - newValue);
            });
        }
```

Comment: Don't use $watch. Use ng-change on the input.

Comment: yes.i try that also.but problem is that when i changed the value i can get the current value only.I can not get the old value.So how can i compare what type of change it is (increasing or decreasing) and how much change there is

Comment: Store the initial values of both columns in memory. Each time the second quantity is changed, compute the difference with the initial value, and apply the same difference to the first quantity.

Comment: i try that too.i copied database data in different two list.one use for table loop and the other one for checking.problem is when i make change in table it changes in both list

Comment: Then post your code, so that we can help you find where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of structure we use on our project.

```
scope.$watch('vm.param.property', (new, old) => {
  const partner = vm.param.otherProperty;
  partner.value = partner.value + (new - old);
});
```

That should link your two values. I haven't tested this btw, taking it from memory of having done it fairly recently.

EDIT: If you place this inside the constructor, then the 2nd line needs to be 'this' instead of 'vm'.

Comment: do i have to do anything in html for fire this code?

Comment: No you shouldn't need to do anything, Mohammad.